# Keep old kernels that are known to work

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel, multiple-monitors

I just upgraded Ubuntu and my external monitors no longer worked, Display Link driver crashed.  So I booted into the old kernel (5.15.0-41-generic) and all is fine.

My concern is if I upgrade again the working kernel will be auto removed.

How many kernels will be kept?  If it is only two can I increase the number?

I have seen posts suggesting editing files generated by /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal, however that file doesn't exist on my set up as far as I can tell (Ubuntu 22.04.1).

Comment: The currently-running kernel, which is likely to be the one that works, won't be auto-removed. So simply make sure that your external monitors work properly before starting an upgrade.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The actual problem seems that your external monitors don't always work with a new kernel. There are many possible causes for that, many with simple solutions. Preventing kernel upgrades is not necessarily the best solution.